# Fail in recursion with odd numbers

Tags: c, recursion

I have just write this funtion to print a list with the numbers between `a` and `b`.

```
void list(int a, int b){

  if(a == b){
    printf("%d", a);
  }else{
    if(a < b){
      printf("%d ", a);
      printf("%d ", b);
      list(a + 1, b - 1);
    }
    if(b < a){
      printf("%d ", a);
      printf("%d ", b);
      list(a - 1, b + 1);
    }
  }

}
```

When I call from the `main` the funtion, it works just when the number of numbers is odd. For example:

```
int main(){

  list(2, 8);

  return 0;
}
```

It works correctly and it prints: `2 8 3 7 4 6 5`. But in this case:

```
int main(){

  list(2, 7);

  return 0;
}
```

It prints `2 7 3 6 4 5 5 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 5 4 4...` forever.

What is wrong in the function??

Comment: It should be obvious that if both numbers are odd, or both are even, they will become equal, but if one is odd and the other even they will pass each other without equality. For example, if they are `4` and `5` then they become `5` and `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it never ends. When the difference between a and b is odd, they never reach the == condition and it continues forever. To solve this, you can check if a and b are going to pass each other, kike this:

```
void list(int a, int b)
{
    if(a == b)
        printf("%d", a);

    else if(a < b)
    {
        printf("%d ", a);
        printf("%d ", b);
        
        if (a + 1 != b)
            list(a + 1, b - 1);
    }

    else if(b < a)
    {
        printf("%d ", a);
        printf("%d ", b);
        
        if (b + 1 != a)
            list(a - 1, b + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As everytime you are making an iteration, you are substracting/adding 1 to both `a` and `b`. This means that when it is an odd number and a pair number `a` and `b` Will never be the same. I recommend you that when you start learning basic algorithms (specially for recursivion) you try some iterations on paper.

**EDIT:** A recommendation would be to simply add an exit clause (another else if), where you exit recursión if `a` becomes bigger than `b` (or viceversa, depending on which number was higher, you could save it in a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

(2,7)

2 7 3 6 4 5

When a = 4, b = 5, the next is a = 5, b = 4, so you got the loop.

try this:

```
void list(int a, int b){ 
  if ( ( b-a ) % 2  == 0 ){ // even
    if(a == b){
    printf("%d", a);
  }else{
  if(a < b){
    printf("%d ", a);
    printf("%d ", b);
    list(a + 1, b - 1);
  }// if
    else if(b < a){
      printf("%d ", a);
      printf("%d ", b);
      list(a - 1, b + 1);
    }
  }
}
else { // odd
  if(a < b){
    printf("%d ", a);
    printf("%d ", b);
    list(a + 1, b - 1);
  }  // if
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each turn when a is not equal to b, you are incrementing one(of a or b) and reducing the other. so the difference between the numbers now decrease by 2 (or increase by 2). Simple observation says that for termination of the re-calling the function, the numbers (a,b) have to be equal. so, for the difference to be 0 (a=b, which will not call the function again), the difference between a and b in the starting should be a multiple of 2. so only both even or both odd are acceptable. In other situations, the function will be called again and again and a particular sequence will repeat(in your case 4 5 5 4)